# How to match two C-style arrays into google mock?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I would like to check if the `rbMapDataSecS_VerifySHA` function is called with these two C-style arrays.
I can't write `With` twice.
How can I get it?

> Process finished with exit code 1
> Failure
> .With() cannot appear more than once in an EXPECT_CALL().

```
EXPECT_CALL(g_objRbMapDataSecSMock, rbMapDataSecS_VerifySHA(_,size,_,buffSize))
                .With(Args<0, 1>(ElementsAreArray(data.begin(), data.end())))
                .With(Args<2, 3>(ElementsAreArray(buffer.begin(), buffer.end())))
                .Times(1)
                .WillRepeatedly(Return(map_data_sec_RET_OK));
```

Comment: You should be looking for matchers: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md

Comment: Please provide [mcve], you can [start with this](https://godbolt.org/z/ez6Ez7). Note we do not see prototype of `rbMapDataSecS_VerifySHA` so we are unable to tell what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I read a more carefully error message and problem is quite simple.

Here is MCVE where I strip your implementation detail, reproduce it and fix it:

```cpp
using testing::_;
using testing::AllOf;
using testing::Args;

struct TestMock {
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, foo, (int a, int b), ());
};


TEST(MockUseWith, ReproduceIt)
{
    TestMock mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(_, _))
        .With(Args<0>(1))
        .With(Args<1>(2));

    mock.foo(1, 2);
}

TEST(MockUseWith, FixIt)
{
    TestMock mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo(_, _))
        .With(AllOf(Args<0>(1), Args<1>(2)));

    mock.foo(1, 2);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sajvrj